# java game smooth movement

Tags: java, game-physics, keylistener

I've understood that to achieve fluid movement for a java image I have to set `booleans` and then trigger actions from that state.
I've tried to set it up in the run loop but the sprite isn't moving. I've tried dubugging it and it goes inside every method so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
public void run(){
    while (running){
    go();
    repaint();
    System.out.println("The game runs");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000/60);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}


//PAINT GRAPHICS
public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, this);
    g.drawImage(sprite, cordX, cordY, this);


}

//LOAD IMAGES
public void load (){
            try {
        String bgpath = "res/bg.png";
        bg = ImageIO.read(new File (sfondopath));
        String spritepath = "res/sprite.png";
        sprite = ImageIO.read(new File (spritespath));
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


//MOVEMENT
public void go(){
    cordX += vX;
    cordX += vY;

}

public void gameupdate(){
    vX=0;
    vY=0;
    if (down) vY = speed;
    if (up) vY = -speed;
    if (left) vX = -speed;
    if (right) vX = speed;
}



public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {
     switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
     //if the right arrow in keyboard is pressed...
     case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
         down = true;
     }
     break;
     //if the left arrow in keyboard is pressed...
     case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
         up = true;
     }
     break;
     //if the down arrow in keyboard is pressed...
     case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: {
         right = true;
     }
     break;
     //if the up arrow in keyboard is pressed...
     case KeyEvent.VK_UP: {
         left = true;
     }
     break;
 }
 gameupdate();
}




public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {

     switch (ke.getKeyCode()) {
     //if the right arrow in keyboard is pressed...
     case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: {
         down = false;
     }
     break;
     //if the left arrow in keyboard is pressed...
     case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: {
         up = false;
     }
     break;
     //if the down arrow in keyboard is pressed...
     case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: {
         right = false;
     }
     break;
     //if the up arrow in keyboard is pressed...
     case KeyEvent.VK_UP: {
         left = false;
     }
     break;
 }
 gameupdate();

}
```

Comment: seems like break is out of case block

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the event dispatch thread with your while loop. That gives swing no chance to actually paint anything. Use a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.

For you it would be roughly:

```
ActionListener gameLoop = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        go();
        repaint();
        System.out.println("The game runs");
   }
};

Timer timer = new Timer(1000/60, gameLoop);

public void run() {
    timer.start();
}
```

You can call `timer.stop()` where you'd normally unset `running`.